# not able to sign in using database with Spring security

Tags: database, spring-mvc, spring-security

I tried user login with database for this example but I am unable to log in. I am always getting error as bad credential even though I am providing right username and password. This is my code:
**login.jsp**

```
<form name="login" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST"> 
    <input type='text' name='username' />             
    <input type='password' name='password'>                      
    <input name="submit" type="submit">&nbsp;<input name="reset" type="reset">
</form>
```

and my queries are same as like to this link http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/ and my **spring-security.xml** is

```
<http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/signin"  access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"></intercept-url>
    <form-login login-page="/signin" authentication-failure-url="/denied"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout"></logout>
</http>
<authentication-manager>  
    <authentication-provider>  
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="select username,password,'true' as enabled from users where username=? limit 1" authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username =?"/>
    </authentication-provider>         
 </authentication-manager>
```

and this is my **spring-database.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">     
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="userroot" />
    </bean>     
</beans>
```

And my **securityconfig.java** and app **config.java** are same..just username value is root and password=userroot. Any help for this?

Answer (score 0):

In your **login.jsp** form you must use `j_username` and `j_password` as names of inputs.

Comment: @Tkachuk_Evgen..no Still the same error....not able to login..unauthorizes access..